# Npgsql: Does Connection Idle Lifetime affect Connections in the Idle In Transaction state?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, connection-string, npgsql

Will connections in the "Idle in Transaction" state be closed if the Connection Idle Lifetime is exceeded, or will only connections in the "Idle" state be closed?

On background, the [documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html) for Connection Idle Lifetime states:

> The time (in seconds) to wait before closing idle connections in the
>   pool if the count of all connections exceeds MinPoolSize. Since 3.1
>   only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Connections that are "idle in transaction" are in-use by a user, in the sense that they're not sitting idly in the connection pool waiting for someone to allocate them. As the quoted doc says, only "idle connections in the pool" are affected - if they're idle in the pool they can't be in a transaction.